# OnSaveInstanceState/OnRestoreInstanceState with java collections

Tags: java, android, onactivityresult, activity-lifecycle

Is a good approach to save java collections when using `onsaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState` flow?

I have an activity that populates some information using some java collections (for example an `ArrayList` containing objects of type A). This information is populated in a `ListView`, like normal android applications do. Additionally, each row will start a detail activity for result (`startActivityForResult(...)`) and is expected to do some updates when it returns (using onActivityResult).

For testing purposes, i enabled the "Don't keep activities" on the device developer preferences to see if the application crashes. Logically, when my parent activity is removed, all objects will be gone. When i return to that activity (`onActivityResult` is executed) my list is empty/null.

My question is, is good approach to save my list in `onSaveInstanceState` and restore is on `onRestoreInstanceState` method in order to prevent empty lists or is enough to check if the list is null on `onActivityResult` method? That will depend on my activities logic? Or it is good practice to save all items that will be used on `onActivityResult` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you don't do it your app crashes right? :)
I think it's a good approach to save all your objects with `onSaveInstanceState` because `Android` will only restore your `Views` layout logic, not your data model logic, that's up to you. And don't forget that you are experiencing this in `onActivityResult` but if your app goes to background let's say you receive a phone call, when you get back, `onResume` will be called and your data model will be null at that point too. So the Activity life-cycle  `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` should always be implemented if you need to persist your data model. Of course it will depend on your logic because if you fetch all your data in `onResume` you'll never have this issue.

More here:
[onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and
[onRestoreInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)

ps: your `Objects` need to implement `Serializable` or `Parcelable`